# Cypress interact with Metamask Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, cypress, blockchain, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I have a website related to blockchain. I am using cypress to execute automation testing for this site. I have problem when cypress interact with Metamask extension.
Embeeded chrome in Cypress can load Metamask extentsion but

- With first time using: I have to input seed phase by hand 1 time before.
- With other times: I have to input password by hand before

My question: How to configure cypress auto fill password or seed phase automatically.
My code is bellow:

cypress.config.ts:
...
on('before:browser:launch', (browser = {}, launchOptions) => {
launchOptions.extensions.push('D:/Research/META3/metamask-chrome-10.15.0')
// How to set password /seedpharse for Metamask extentsion.
return launchOptions
})

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.